# View Controllers, Dependency Injection, and init/viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, dependency-injection, initialization

I've read a bunch of answers on SO already, but I'm a little confused.

I have a tab bar controller subclass I created, and in its viewDidLoad, I'm creating each of the view controllers. However, I have a dependency that I'm passing into the parent, and in turn into the view controller for each tab. I'm passing that dependency in with a custom init method (NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER declared for it in the header). However, it looks like `[super init]` triggers viewDidLoad directly, so the dependency isn't set properly when the other view controllers are created.

Here's my custom init method:

```
- (instancetype)initWithSession:(T2Session *)session
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _session = session;
    }

    return self;
}
```

I'd like `session` to be set by the time I create the view controllers, but I'm sort of confused about what the best way to do this is. Any advice is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Calling init doesn't cause viewDidLoad to be called. The viewDidLoad method is called for the controller in the first tab because the tab bar controller adds that controller's view to its view. None of the other controllers should have viewDidLoad called until you click on their tab.

Comment: Hmm...I set a breakpoint in viewDidLoad of my tab bar controller, and the stack trace pointed directly to my `self = [super init];` line...

Comment: Init in any controller should not lead directly to the view being loaded. In the case of the tab bar controller, its view is loaded (somehow) by the system because it's the window's rootViewController, and that leads to viewDidLoad being called.

Comment: Why not create the child view controllers in the init method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across this situation before.
You probably sat there (like me) wishing `viewDidLoad` didn't get called so soon.

Anyway, this is what I settled on:

```
- (instancetype)initWithSession:(T2Session *)session {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.session = session;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setSession:(T2Session *)session {
  _session = session;

  ... call the setup methods here, instead of viewDidLoad
}
```

At first I thought this breaks the *golden rule* of not calling `self.xxxx` from within an initializer.
However, I think that rule is only really relevant when calling methods on IBOutlets that may not have been wired up yet.
In this case, `T2Session *session` isn't a nib outlet.

Alternatively, if you prefer not to break that rule you could always remove the custom initializer .. and revert to using regular property-injection rather than constructor-injection. e.g.

```
T2Session *session = .....

MYTabBarController *tabBarController = [[MYTabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController setSession:session];
```

These are just my thoughts, hope it helps.

Comment: also make sure you call _session = session at the beginning of the setSession: method

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the advice! Still haven't done anything about this, but i'm going to think on it more.